# jQuery .css() api result is different between chrome and ie11

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer

*Simply put....*

**CHROME**

```
$("#background").css("background-image")
// Above api produces ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
// "url(http://img.tenasia.hankyung.com/webwp_kr/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014081512142367297.jpg)"
```

**IE11**

```
$("#background").css("background-image")
// Above api produces ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
// "url("http://img.tenasia.hankyung.com/webwp_kr/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014081512142367297.jpg")"
```

**I'm trying to**

pull out the url address using `substring()`. But the difference between those two browsers bothers me. How can I get the url in both browsers? or what would be the best alternatives?

I also tried this but as expected, it produces the same result.

```
$("#background")[0].style.backgroundImage
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: There is a second `"`before `http` and at the end in the IE example in case anyone else is looking at that wondering what the difference is

Comment: @scniro right, IE produces a `url()` clause with the URL quoted. Is that it?

Comment: @Pointy I'd imagine that is the issue, OP please confirm

Comment: The problem occurs at `substring()` step. Because IE has two more `"` at the beginning and the end in the `.css()` result.

Comment: either replace the " with nothing, or use a reg exp.

Answer (score 0):

```
var bgurl= $("#background").css("background-image");
bgurl = bgurl.replace(bgurl.indexOf('url("') != -1 ? 'url("' : 'url(' , '').replace(bgurl.indexOf('url("') != -1 ? '")' : ')' , '');
```